# Setting up git web hook to point to jekyll-hook on nginx? What should be the payload URL?

Tags: git, nginx, jekyll, webhooks

I'm trying to set up [Jekyll-hook](https://github.com/developmentseed/jekyll-hook), but since I'm new to git and nginx, I'm stuck. I have nginx running on Digital Ocean's LEMP stack. What should be the Payload URL?

I'm also having problems with the last part of the guide of Jekyll-hook, which says the following:

> Configure a webserver (nginx)
>
> The default publish.sh is setup for nginx and copies _site folder to
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rep_name.
>
> If you would like to copy the website to another location, make sure
>   to update nginx virtual hosts which is located at
>   /etc/nginx/nginx/site-available on Ubuntu 14.
>
> You also need to update publish.sh

Now, my sites are in the /var/www/html/ folder, not in /usr/share/nginx/html/

Whats up with that? Can I get a little clarification please?